# undo remove operation in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongohq

I run by mistake a db.collection_name.remove({condition:'true'}) from console
and delete object I didn't plan to delete, can I recover them some how?

I db is on mongohq, if it can helps?

Comment: You could also use [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) next time, as it returns the deleted object.

Answer (score 14):

It's too late now, but to prevent this from happening again, you can add a member to your replset with priority 0 and slaveDelay set to an hour or so, so that it will be (at least) an hour behind the primary. This member could serve as an oops-I-probably-shouldn't-have-hit-enter-quite-yet recovery.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB itself has no mechanismn to undo deletions. As your DB is hosted in the cloud, you will probably also not be able to do any OS-based recovery (such as Time Machine on Mac) even though I've never used MongoHQ so far to know for sure.

As you can read in the [MongoHQ Doc](http://support.mongohq.com/backups/overview.html) a (free) recovery is not possible, you are rather encouraged to back up the data yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using NoSqlBooster, you could find the deleted document if you made a `find` operation before deleting it.

You can click on Show Log at the right bottom corner, and see the last queries **including their results**. Just look for the query with the relevant result and then double click on its "result" column. Now you can just copy the relevant document and insert it again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if You've mongorestore working or installed, You can restore bson file by importing .bson

```
mongorestore -d db_name -c collection_name /path/file.bson
```